# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list, but I don't see the fault

Tags: python, list

```
def switch(g, p,n):
    final = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        d = list(range(n))
        d.remove(g[i])
        d.remove(p[i])

        final.append(d)

    return final

switch([2, 3, 0], [[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
9],[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],11)
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-151-72e1cc5c9abf> in <module>()
     10     return final
     11 
---> 12 switch([2, 3, 0], [[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],11)



<ipython-input-151-72e1cc5c9abf> in switch(g, p, n)
      4         d = list(range(n))
      5         d.remove(g[i])
----> 6         d.remove(p[i])
      7 
      8         final.append(d)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want the numbers of g and p removed from the list and that I get the number that is left as output.

Comment: `p` contains lists, not integers.  Why would `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` be in `range(n)`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I understand what you say, but how do I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect the ouput to look like?

Comment: I want that whenever n = 11, d is a list from 0 to 10. so [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, ,7 ,8, 9, 10]. Then [2,3,0] as list of g and [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],[1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]] as lists of p. I want the output to remove 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and only remains 10 of that list, the next list only contains 8 and the last one only 9.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh So the output has to be 3 numbers that are not in g and p.

Comment: There are no numbers in p. There are 3 lists in p. There are numbers in those lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
def switch(g, p, n):
    out = []
    for exclude, exclude_list in zip(g, p):
        out.append([x for x in range(n) if x != exclude and x not in exclude_list])
    return out

switch([2, 3, 0], [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]], 11)
# [[10], [8], [9]]
```

Instead of removing items from a list, we are instead going to only make the sublists with items that are not excluded.